# Installation OCI8 extension to MAMP not works

Tags: php, mamp, oci8, mamp-pro

I followed a few steps from `http://caseymorford.com` to install the OCI8 extension. The only issue was that the install-path on success was different. So I copied the `oci8.so` file to the right folder.

After restarting Apache and running some php, i still get the message:

```
 Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

Is there some other way to download a complete > PHP5.4 version with a build in oci extension?

Comment: I haven't done this on MacOS, but on Windows you just need the basic instantclient extracted to a directory, like `c:\instantclient` and then include that in your system path.  PHP has to be able to find the `oci.dll` (`oci.dylib`?) on load.

Comment: [These instructions](http://antistatique.net/blog/2013/03/25/install-php-oracle-oci-extension-11-2-on-mac-os-x-10-8/) look a lot more like what I would expect.